# LINQ to XML simple query

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML doc like this:

```
<Persons>
 <Person Id="10000" FullName="Jon Doe">
  <Status StatusID="1" StatusDesc="Active"/>
      <Fields>
          <Field FieldId="1" Value="xxxx"/>
          <Field FieldId="2" Value="yyyy"/>
          <Field FieldId="2" Value="zzzz"/>
      </Fields>
 </Person>
 <Person Id="10001" FullName="John Smith">
  <Status StatusID="2" StatusDesc="New"/>
  <Fields>
      <Field FieldId="3" Value="aaaa"/>
      <Field FieldId="4" Value="bbbb"/>
     <Field FieldId="5" Value="ccccv"/>
  </Fields>
 </Person>
</Persons>
```

I want to write an XML query that returns the "Person" ID and all "Fields" elements.
I can get all "Fields" elements but not the "Person" ID. 
The same applies when I need the "Status" element.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result = XElement.Load("Example.xml")
  .Elements("Person")
  .Select(p => new {
   Id = p.Attribute("Id").Value,
   Fields = p.Descendants("Field").Select(f => new {
      Id = f.Attribute("FieldId").Value,
      Value = f.Attribute("Value").Value
     })
  });
```

This will give you a sequence of anonymous types that look something like this:

```
class Anonymous
{
    public String Id { get; }
    public IEnumerable<AnonymousSubtype> Fields { get; }
}

class AnonymousSubtype
{
   public String Id { get; }
   public String Value { get; }
}
```

The reason that I used the `Descendants` method to retrieve the fields is because the element I am first working with is the `Person` element.  Since `Elements` only returns nodes that are direct children it would not work to retrieve the fields so I used `Descendants` instead.

To enumerate the results you can do this:

```
foreach (var person in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Person Id: {0}", person.Id);
    foreach (var field in person.Fields)
    {
        Console.Write("  Field Id: {0}", field.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("  Field Value: {0}", field.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @anon2010 - I simplified the query a bit - it is the same query just with a simplified approach.

Comment: Ty Andrew, that "let fields" statement confused me a bit. Why you used p.Descendants("Field") and not p.Elements("Field")?

Comment: Also, how can I foreach the result??

Comment: @anon2010 - I have updated my answer rather than commenting. To much stuff for a comment! :)

Comment: Andrew, I've tested the code last night and it works fine except when some "Person" elements has no "Field" Descendants. Then I'm getting a "null reference" error. Any ideas?

Comment: The same happens if I call  Fields = p.Descendants("Field").Select or  Fields = p.Descendants("Fields").Elements("Field").Select

Comment: @anon2010 - Can you provide a sample of the XML you have that is causing the code to throw an exception?  Feel free to throw the code into the original question.